# Audio slider and pause/play buttons not working on audio (flutter)

Tags: flutter, audio

I am trying to build a messaging app using flutter and I want to be able to send audio messages. The audio layout is great and the audio is working properly on button click however the slider and the pause/play button are not updating.
This is my widgets code:

```
Widget buildItem(int index, DocumentSnapshot? document) {
bool isPlaying = false;
final audioplayers.AudioPlayer audioPlayer = audioplayers.AudioPlayer();

Duration duration = Duration.zero;
Duration position = Duration.zero;

void playAudio(String path) async {
  if (isPlaying) {
    await audioPlayer.stop();
    if (currentAudioPath == path) {
      setState(() {
        isPlaying = false;
        currentAudioPath = null;
      });
      return;
    }
  } else {
    await audioPlayer.play(audioplayers.DeviceFileSource(path));
  }
  setState(() {
    isPlaying = true;
    currentAudioPath = path;
  });
}

void _launchURL(String url) async {
  if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.dataFromString(url))) {
    await launchUrl(Uri.dataFromString(url));
  } else {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Could not launch URL');
  }
}

audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((state) {
  setState(() {
    isPlaying = state == audioplayers.PlayerState.playing;
  });
});

audioPlayer.onDurationChanged.listen((newDuration) {
  setState(() {
    duration = newDuration;
  });
});

audioPlayer.onPositionChanged.listen((newPosition) {
  setState(() {
    position = newPosition;
  });
});

if (document != null) {
  ChatMessages messageChat = ChatMessages.fromDocument(document);
  final isCurrentUserMessage = messageChat.senderId == currentUserId;
  Widget messageWidget;
  Widget messageContent = Text(
    messageChat.message,
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
  );

  // Check if the message contains links
  if (messageChat.message.isURL) {
    // Wrap the message content with Linkify widget to convert links to clickable links
    messageContent = Linkify(
      onOpen: (link) => _launchURL(link.url),
      text: messageChat.message,
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
      linkStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
    );
  }

  WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    scrollToEnd();
  });

  messageWidget = Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      messageChat.type == MessageType.text
          ? Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 250),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 12),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                color: isCurrentUserMessage ? whiteColor : lightGreyColor,
              ),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: isLastMessageRight(index)
                    ? CrossAxisAlignment.end
                    : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  messageContent,
                  SizedBox(height: 4),
                  Text(
                    DateFormat('hh:mm').format(messageChat.timestamp),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: meduimGreyColor),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 0,
                bottom: 2,
                right: isLastMessageRight(index) ? 10 : 0,
                left: isLastMessageRight(index) ? 0 : 10,
              ),
            )
          : messageChat.type == MessageType.image
              ? Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color:
                        isCurrentUserMessage ? whiteColor : lightGreyColor,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                  ),
                  child: OutlinedButton(
                    child: Material(
                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                            child: Image.network(
                              messageChat.message,
                              width: 200,
                              height: 200,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            bottom: 4,
                            right: isLastMessageRight(index) ? 4 : null,
                            left: isLastMessageRight(index) ? null : 4,
                            child: Text(
                              DateFormat('hh:mm')
                                  .format(messageChat.timestamp),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 12, color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => FullPhotoPage(
                            url: messageChat.message,
                            date: DateFormat('hh:mm')
                                .format(messageChat.timestamp),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(
                        EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 0,
                    bottom: 2,
                    right: 10,
                  ),
                )
              : messageChat.type == MessageType.location
                  ? Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      color: isCurrentUserMessage
                          ? whiteColor
                          : lightGreyColor,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: 400.0,
                      child: FlutterMap(
                        options: MapOptions(
                          //center: LatLng(0, 0),
                          zoom: 13.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  : messageChat.type == MessageType.audio
                      ? GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            playAudio(messageChat.message);
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: isCurrentUserMessage
                                  ? whiteColor
                                  : lightGreyColor,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                            ),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    isPlaying
                                        ? Icons.pause
                                        : Icons.play_arrow,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    playAudio(messageChat.message);
                                  },
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 10),
                                Expanded(
                                    child: Slider(
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    // Seek to a specific position in the audio
                                    audioPlayer.seek(
                                        Duration(seconds: value.toInt()));
                                  },
                                  value: position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                                  min: 0,
                                  max: duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                                )),
                                Text(
                                  '${position.inMinutes}:${(position.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}',
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      : Container()
    ],
    mainAxisAlignment: messageChat.senderId == currentUserId
        ? MainAxisAlignment.end
        : MainAxisAlignment.start,
  );

  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
    child: messageWidget,
  );
} else {
  return SizedBox.shrink();
} }
```

I need help fixing my audio layout.
Thank you.